# Single login to access multiple APIs (in-house and externals)

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I'd like to build a single app where the user would login and then that app will communicate with some in-house API but let's say it can also communicate with external API like maybe twitter api, facebook api, amazon api, etc.

Does this means that I'll have to keep like a mapping with my users and the external api users like my in-house UserA is actually UserB in Twitter, so that when UserA logs into my system and the pages display UserA tweets it can somehow ask the twitter api the tweets of UserB? Somehow I'll have to keep the UserB twitter credentials in-house somewhere so I can impersonate it?

Is this how I should proceed or there exist some standard for this kind of scenario?

Comment: What's the use case? What do you expect will happen if the user is not logged into e.g. Twitter?

Comment: Let's say a timeline app which displays facebook timeline and twitter timeline in a SPA web interface. I just want to user to login into mysupertime.com/login using his credentials on mysupertime.com and then the home page shows FB timeline and Twitter timeline. So for this to happens, I guess I have to store FB and twitter credentials (api keys for example) mapped to that specific user somewhere on mysupertime.com? Any existing solution for this ?